# Retrieve column definition from sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have dynamic query which returns different table results. Results can have different number of columns and different column names.

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Query,N'@parameter nvarchar(19)',@parameter=@parameter
```

I can retrieve column definition of the stored procedure by using

```
exec sp_describe_first_result_set N''
```

But how I can retrieve column definition or just get column names from `sp_executesql`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[sp_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  works with arbitrary batches, so just run:

```
exec sp_describe_first_result_set @Query
```

Comment: And no temporary tables. It's amazing! Thank you!